# React Native MainActivity.java ReactActivityDelegateWrapper() how to merge two necessary methods

Tags: java, react-native, android-activity, react-native-gesture-handler

code to modify:

```java
@Override
  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new ReactActivityDelegateWrapper(this, BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED, new DefaultReactActivityDelegate(
        this,
        getMainComponentName(),
        // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable the Fabric Renderer.
        DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.getFabricEnabled(), // fabricEnabled
        // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable Concurrent React (i.e. React 18).
        DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.getConcurrentReactEnabled() // concurrentRootEnabled
        ));
  }
```

need to modify **new DefaultReactActivityDelegate** call to include curly brackets with @Override like here:

```java
@Override
     protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
       return new DefaultReactActivityDelegate(
           this,
           getMainComponentName(),
           // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable the Fabric Renderer.
           DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.getFabricEnabled(), // fabricEnabled
           // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable Concurrent React (i.e. React 18).
           DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.getConcurrentReactEnabled() // concurrentRootEnabled
       ) {
         @Override
         protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
           return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
         }
       };
     }
```